# Fixed Column Tables positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add vertical scroll in the table which  has first column fixed .

I have  a horizontally scrolling table  and I want the first column to stick.but when table height increases beyond the div's height then the first column is positioned outside . mainly because it has fixed position . I am not getting a fix for this.

My html is as,

```
   <div class="table-wrapper">
<table id="consumption-data" class="data">
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>Item 2</th>
            <th>Item 3</th>
            <th>Item 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="results">
        <tr>
            <th>Jan</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Feb</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Mar</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Apr</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <th>May</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Jun</th>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
            <td>3163</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and css as,

```
  .table-wrapper { 
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:visible;
width:250px;
margin-left: 120px;
height:200px;
  }


td, th {
padding: 5px 20px;
width: 100px;
}

 th:first-child {
position: fixed;
left: 5px
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o6ywngjv/)

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the answer As pointed out on my answer's comment below.

You need to update your HTML structure in order to achieve that by using DIV instead of table (may not be the ideal solution).
There is no way to achieve it by using your current HTML structure unless if you can tolerate to freeze the first column from scrolling vertically, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/catapago/vfc31ch5/).

If you think it through you are trying to make 2 children elements `<th>` and `<td>` able to scroll vertically but one child element remains static while scrolling horizontally. `absolute` and `fixed` position cancel out the later constraint.

Comment: The questions says that it needs a vertical scroll also . As per your solution the vertical scroll is lost

Answer (score 0):

add this css code

```
tr{
     margin-left: 120px;
}
```

and remove

```
th:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Sticky Table](https://github.com/armaaar/JQuery-Sticky-Table) jQuery plugin. You can use it to have a fixed column without changing your table structure.